# PHP - Check If Username Exists Or If Submitted Username Is Current

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to check if the entered username already exists or if the entered username is the current username.

I've Googled various SO questions but none seem to check if the current username is the submitted one.

The problem with the following code; it doesn't matter if the username is taken or not, it will still let you save.

```
$stmt = $engine->runQuery("SELECT user_name, user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:username OR user_email=:email");
$stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username, ':email'=>$email));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(strtolower($row['user_name']) == strtolower($username) || $username !== $row['user_name']) {
    $engine->authapi(false, 'Sorry, username is already taken. Please choose a different one.');
} elseif(strtolower($row['user_email']) == strtolower($email) && $email !== $_SESSION['user_email']) {
    $engine->authapi(false, 'Email is already registered. You cannot use the same emails for multiple accounts.');
} else {
    // save
}
```

How can I make it so it checks if the username is taken or not, and at the same time check if the submitted username is the current username (if so, let the user save)?

Comment: Try replacing `==` with `===` while comparing strings

Comment: Isn't it an uppercase/lowercase problem?

Comment: @biziclop When removing the `$username !== $row['user_name']` it does error that the username is taken.

Comment: if lowercase username = lowercase row username, or if username doesn't equal row username? Your if statement is borked

Comment: Can you explain why its borked @delboy1978uk? `$username !== $row['user_name']`: $username is the $_POST'ed value, the `$row['user_name']` is basically the same value, but taken from the database query

Comment: well, you say if they are equal, or if they are not equal. It's always going to be one or the other

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are several issues in your code.

1) Your SQL. You can fetch more than one row here, for example you have two entries in your database, `username: maio290, e-mail: a@foo.bar` and `username: maio291, e-mail: b@foo.bar`. Now your user enteres username: `maio290` and e-mail: `b@foo.bar` which will result in two entries selected. Most likely an edge case, but a valid one.

2) Your if: You're comparing `strtolower($row['user_name']) == strtolower($username)` OR `$username !== $row['user_name'])` - the second one doesn't make any sense with your error. Since that means: "hey, your user is not in our database, please take a different one" Also, the first comparision could be a lot nicer with using `strcasecmp`.

I would really split these two options, since it's a lot better to read and you don't have the problem with two selectable rows. Also, you let your database handle the comparision.

Therefore I would write the code like that:

```
<?PHP
// Select if username is taken
$stmt = $engine->runQuery("SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name=:username");
$stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if(count($row) != 0)
{
    $engine->authapi(false, 'Sorry, username is already taken. Please choose a different one.');
    // I would actually return here, so we wouldn't need an else
}
else
{
    // check if e-mail is registred
    $stmt = $engine->runQuery("SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE user_email=:email");
    $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$email));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(count($row) != 0)
    {
        $engine->authapi(false, 'Email is already registered. You cannot use the same emails for multiple accounts.');
    }
    else
    {
        // store
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, maio290! My main problem was checking if the current loggedin username (`$_SESSION['user_name']`) is the submitted username (`$username`) - this because it's used for editing the profile - your code would work fine if it's used for user registration purposes, but if a user tries edit their profile and saves the form, it would say their *current username* is already in use. Do you have a possible solution to that?